# Multiple endpoints for single WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a WCF Service. There are multiple Operation Contract for the service. Among them, only one [Operation Contract] will be as JSON data.

For Example:---
Service Name: IAdmin.cs

```
[OperationContract]
DataSet GetReport(int userID);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", UriTemplate="/getDetails?name={name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
Admin_UserDetails getUserDetails();
```

In the above code, the first [Operation Contract] will be returning XML message format.
The second one will be returning in JSON format.

Now, my question is that will I have to create another service for the JSON [Operation Contract] or is it ok to write in the same service?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple endpoints and bindings on a single service is actually a strength of the WCF. I think [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx) will help you.

Comment: Ok. I looked into that and it is showing "basicHttpBinding" and "wsHttpbinding". But, In my case, its "basicHttpBinding" and "webHttpBinding", where one of the [Operation Contract] is returning data in JSON. To return data in JSON, I had to write the [Operation Contract] with the attributes like "WebInvoke" with "Method" property etc. but the other [Opeartion Contract](s) are not been declared with any WebGet/WebInvoke property. So, can it be done like that or I will have to write a whole new service for the JSON [Operation Contract]?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what exactly your problem is. Do you want to restrict the GetReport-method to your xml endpoint, and the Admin_UserDetails-Method to your json endpoint? If that's the case you need to define two service interfaces. You can, however, still host both of them on one service.

Comment: Yes that is what I want exactly. GetReport method for xml and Admin_UserDetails for JSON. Ok, so I need to write two different services for both of them. But, I can create multiple endpoints for a service. Now, if the client want to return data in xml as well as json, then we can create multiple endpoints for them within the service, in web.config. Isn't it? Then why it is required to create two different services in this case? Thanks a lot, by the way.

Comment: Because a service is defined by the interface it implements. Anything that is decorated with the OperationContractAttribute will be published. So if you want make different set of methods available, the thing you really want to do is to literally publish two interfaces. This is exactly what the word "interface" means. The binding, and thus, the _type_ of answer a client would receive, does not matter in that. You've got two different services you want to offer, that's why you need to implement two, and THEN you can go all nuts about setting the bindings on these.

Comment: So, it means that suppose I have one Service named as IAdmin.cs. now, I cannot be able to create two operation contracts, one having [WebInvoke / WebGet] attribute (JSON) and another does not have any such attribute (XML). Am I right? Anyways, I implemented two different services for them and facing CORS issue now and already posted the issue in stackOverflow.com, just few seconds back